# Prevent application from creating files inside a folder

Tags: google-chrome, browser, malware, scanner

Google Chrome has been injecting their own malware scanner, called Software Reporter Tool, bundled with their browser without any option for the users to select what the malware scanner is allowed to scan, without providing a clear list of what the malware scanner is or will actually do, when it can scan and no way for the user to opt out or turn it off.

This is a serious problem because the scanner fires at random times causing 75% CPU usage during times where development is taking place, dragging the computer speed by a lot while the scanner is ruining.

I have tried to lock permissions to the folder and deleted its contents, both of which are located inside AppData Google folders, yet it always manages to download it again once the browser updates.

How can I permanently deny the browser from downloading and installing this disgusting piece of bloatware once and for all without forgoing the browser itself?

EDIT: This is for the Windows 7 OS

Comment: Windows 10 has a feature that can prevent any changes to a folder.  This means Chrome wouldn't be able to do anything with the folder either.

Comment: I Used Google.......http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-google-chrome-software-reporter-tool

Comment: @Ramhound This is for Windows 7, I've added that note to the question

Comment: @Moab disabling it is not what this question is about and it was already taken into account, described in the question.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn’t have the required feature.  I am not aware of any third-party applications that would provide it, even if, software recommendations were within scope

Comment: @Shadow actually that link has solutions to "Prevent application (Chrome) from creating files inside a folder" Evidently you are doing something wrong when changing permissions on the folder and its contents.

Comment: @Moab You can argue all you want, the fact is I already tried those exact instructions before, they don't work after the browser updates and they are clearly labeled as "Disable Google Chrome Software Reporter Tool", which, again, has nothing to do with what this question is asking for.

Comment: @Shadow don't get mad at me if you cannot block that folder, besides you need to  edit the body of your question to remove this "How can I permanently deny the browser from downloading and installing this disgusting piece of bloatware"

Comment: @Moab The title clearly covers what I convey in the question. Thanks for the suggestion.